# how does jvm manages heap memory with system memory?

Tags: java, performance, jvm

1.How does JVM manages Heap Memory with system memory?

2.What are the points we have to take care in java programming to prevent heap space problem?

Comment: This is Stackoverflow and not Google.com

Comment: What do you mean by heap memory?

Comment: it is heap space memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[1. Understanding Heap Memory Management](http://pubs.vmware.com/vfabric52/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.vfabric.em4j.1.2/em4j/conf-heap-management.html)

[2. Points about java Heap memory space problem](http://javarevisited.blogspot.ro/2011/05/java-heap-space-memory-size-jvm.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know How to handle the heap space Exception in java, but I want to know the programming strategies to prevent heap space exception.

Comment: the strategy to prevent heap space exception is not creating any memory leaks, nothing else :)

Comment: And making sure the heap size fits the needs of the application during peak usage. That also automatically means that the available system memory might need to adapt with it as well. A simple example: if you are going to allow people to load an image of 1GB uncompressed into your application, you definitely need more than 1GB of heap memory. That's simple supply and demand.

Answer (score 2):

**What is Heap Memory in java?**

> When a Java program started Java Virtual Machine gets some memory from
>   Operating System. Java Virtual Machine or JVM uses this memory for all
>   its need and part of this memory is call java heap memory. Heap in
>   Java generally located at bottom of address space and move upwards.
>   whenever we create object using new operator or by any another means
>   object is allocated memory from Heap and When object dies or garbage
>   collected ,memory goes back to Heap space in Java

**Jvm Heap Management?**

> As we know objects are created inside heap memory and Garbage
>   collection is a process which removes dead objects from Java Heap
>   space and returns memory back to Heap in Java. For the sake of Garbage
>   collection Heap is divided into three main regions named as New
>   Generation, Old or Tenured Generation and Perm space. New Generation
>   of Java Heap is part of Java Heap memory where newly created object
>   are stored, During the course of application many objects created and
>   died but those remain live they got moved to Old or Tenured Generation
>   by Java Garbage collector thread on Major or full garbage collection.
>   Perm space of Java Heap is where JVM stores Meta data about classes
>   and methods, String pool and Class level details. You can see How
>   Garbage collection works in Java for more information on Heap in Java
>   and Garbage collection.

**Points to take care in java programming to prevent heap space problem?**

> When JVM starts JVM heap space is equal to the initial size of Heap
>   specified by -Xms parameter, as application progress more objects get
>   created and heap space is expanded to accommodate new objects. JVM
>   also run garbage collector periodically to reclaim memory back from
>   dead objects. JVM expands Heap in Java some where near to Maximum Heap
>   Size specified by -Xmx and if there is no more memory left for
>   creating new object in java heap , JVM throws
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError and your application dies. Before throwing
>   OutOfMemoryError No Space in Java Heap, JVM tries to run garbage
>   collector to free any available space but even after that not much
>   space available on Heap in Java it results into OutOfMemoryError. To
>   resolve this error you need to understand your application object
>   profile i.e. what kind of object you are creating, which objects are
>   taking how much memory etc. you can use profiler or heap analyzer to
>   troubleshoot OutOfMemoryError in Java. "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:
>   Java heap space" error messages denotes that Java heap does not have
>   sufficient space and cannot be expanded further while
>   "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space" error message comes when
>   the permanent generation of Java Heap is full, the application will
>   fail to load a class or to allocate an interned string.
>
> Try to use static variable and methods because they share commom memory.

[Source](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/05/java-heap-space-memory-size-jvm.html)

Comment: "Try to use static variable and methods because they share commom memory." That single statement already proves how poor that random internet resource is.

Comment: @Gimby did I say anything wrong